# Ruby get GET request data

Tags: ruby, axios, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making API endpoints and I'm having trouble getting the body of the request. Here is what I have:

In my routes I have set up an endpoint in my namespace:

```
namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :json}  do
    resources :mainview do
        collection do
            get 'data'
        end
    end
```

In my front end I call the /api/mainview/data endpoint and pass it in a date inside of a json:

```
axios.get('/api/mainview/data', {"start_date":"2020-01-01"})
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("We are getting this error:")
      console.log(error)
    });
```

And then, in my /api/mainview_controller.rb file, I got

```
module Api
    class MainviewController < AuthenticatedController
        def data
            puts "We are in the data function"
            #I want to print the body ({"start_date":"2020-01-01"}) of the request here 
        end
    end
end
```

So in this case, my API call seems to work as `We are in the data function` does get printed to the terminal. However, I don't know how to get the body or data from the request. If it's a post request I know I can use `request.raw_post` but I don't know what to use for GET requests. Most of the answers I found online are in PHP so any help would be great!

Comment: try `params[:start_date]` all parameters passed, whether via GET or POST, will be stored in the `params` Hash and can be accessed by name via `Hash#[]`

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for the reply but it did not work. When i puts params I get the result `{"format"=>:json, "controller"=>"api/mainview", "action"=>"data"}`

Comment: @engineersmnky the params seems to work if I make the axios request using the URL like this: `/api/mainview/data?startDate=2020-01-01`

Comment: According to the [README](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.MD) you need to pass the arguments as `{params:{start_date:"2020-01-01"}}` when making a get request. I havenl never used axios just looked at the common js usage section

Answer (score 0):

You have to render a response through Rails and you have to actually build up the output in the response before Rails packages it up and sends it back.

```
def data
  render json: { 
      start_date: params[:start_date] 
    }
end
```